# Rails Simple Form Gem not setting association id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to use the simple form gem to populate a select box using an association. I have two associated models: `job_category` and `job_type`.

*job_category has_many job_types*

and

*job_type belongs to job_category*.

I'm successfully populating the select box using this form,

```
= simple_form_for(@job_type) do |f|  
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs  
    = f.input :name  
    = f.association :job_category, :include_blank => false, :label_method => :name  
  .form-actions  
    = f.button :submit
```

and it is creating a `job_type` object when I hit my create route, but the `job_category_id` field in `job_type` isn't being set.

When I go to the command line instead, I am able to successfully create a new job using

```
JobType.create(name: "Test", job_category_id: 1)
```

Inspecting the post using the `Chrome developer tools` shows `job_category_id` being sent over as part of the `post`, so I don't have any idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you share the server log generated upon submitting this form. You can get it from the terminal where you are running `rails server`. Add it in the question.

Comment: can you show us your params method that your create action reference to? Are you using accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4, can you confirm that you've added `:job_category_id` to your `job_type_params` method in JobTypesController?

If you have not, make sure `:job_category_id` is in your `job_type_params` method.

If you're using < Rails 4, add `:job_category_id` to your `attr_accessible`.

Comment: This did it. My params method permitted :job_category and it's fields, but not job_category_id.